# LWJGL Creating 3d world

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Need some good book or tutorials on how to start with LWJGL.
Not much interested in 2d but more in 3d.

Interested in creating basic 3d environment such as terrain, lights, basic interaction.

Comment: This is about as broad as questions get. Please try to refine it a tad.

Comment: Pretty much book or tutorial on "Intro into Java 3d Game Development"

Comment: I suggest you first get some theoretical knowledge on computer graphics before starting 3d programming with a specific language/framework, otherwise I suppose I'll read your name quite often in the near future.

Comment: Well if you can suggest basic reading on that, it would work :D

Comment: [nehe.gamedev.net](http://nehe.gamedev.net/lesson.asp?index=02) has lwjgl code for some of the lessons.

Comment: Lots of this is already done -- with source that can be browsed. See [jME: Java Monkey Engine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) and similar. These frameworks can let one bypass lots of the theoretical stuff and start out in a nicely-mapped 3d world.

Answer (score 3):

Start by learning how to use OpenGL. Some good books are the OpenGL redbook, available for free at http://glprogramming.com/red/ and the "OpenGL Superbible" The superbible is really big and intimidating, but it is not that bad if you read the first 3 -5 chapters of the redbook. Both of these books are targeted at C, but the LWJGL org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11 class contains most of the basic methods. Ignore the GLUT, WGL and GLX stuff, because that stuff is handled by the LWJGL classes. For LWJGL specific basics, the wiki is invaluable.